# Matcher java doesn't work but regex seems to be good

Tags: java, regex

I want to find instance of regex in my string.
But it doesn't work.
My regex seems to be good.

My string is like that :

```
LB,32736,0,T,NRJ.POMPES_BACHE.PUISSANCE_ELEC_INST,20190811T080000.000Z,20190811T194400.000Z
TR,NRJ.POMPES_BACHE.PUISSANCE_ELEC_INST,0,65535,1,1,,0,0,2
20190811T080000.000Z,0.00800000037997961,192
20190811T080100.000Z,0.008999999612569809,192
20190811T080200.000Z,0.008999999612569809,192
LB,32734,0,T,NRJ.POMPES_BACHE.PUISSANCE_ELEC_CPT,20190811T080000.000Z,20190811T201200.000Z
TR,NRJ.POMPES_BACHE.PUISSANCE_ELEC_CPT,0,65535,1,1,,0,0,2
20190811T080000.000Z,0.6743068099021912,192
20190811T080100.000Z,0.6744459867477417,192
20190811T080200.000Z,0.6745882630348206,192
20190811T080300.000Z,0.6747232675552368,192
20190811T080400.000Z,0.6748600006103516,192
20190811T080500.000Z,0.6749916672706604,192
20190811T080600.000Z,0.6751362681388855,192
```

And I want to match only lines which have this format

```
20190811T080000.000Z,0.00800000037997961,192
```

So I have tried this regex

```
^([^,]*,){2}[^,]*$
```

And work on this website : https://regex101.com/r/iIbpgB/3

But, when I implement it on Java, it doesn't work.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([^,]*,){2}[^,]*$");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
                if ( matcher.find()){
                    System.out.println(matcher.group());
                }
```

You can verify here : https://www.codiva.io/p/e83bcde1-8528-4330-94a2-58fe80afffc0

Someone have an explain?..
Thanks

Comment: The regex you posted does not match the regex101 example so I totally believe that something is broken for you...

Comment: Yes, it's modify but problem is not here.. I have updated

Comment: I think that regex101 does not have the java flavor. Most is probably the same, but not everything (so many Déjà Vus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are missing `MULTILINE` mode in your Java regex, you may use:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([^,]*,){2}[^,]*$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

or else use inline:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?m)^([^,]*,){2}[^,]*$");
```

Answer (score 1):

You changed between if and while, do you want 1 match or all of them?

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([^,]*,){2}[^,]*$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
while ( matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

This version will keep looping while the matcher continues to match the regex in the content string.

Comment: Yes, i had if for my tests, but it's replaced by while in my code. thanks !